# Error when trying to mount an .iso file

Tags: mount, iso

I try to mount an .iso file.
I use:

```
sudo mkdir /media/fakecd

sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/your.iso /media/fakecd
```

But I get this error message:

```
can't find /media/fakecd in /etc/fstab
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If file pathnames are quoted ( `sudo mount -o loop '/path/to/your.iso' '/media/fakecd'` ) the issue is still there?

Comment: Yes, issue still there

Comment: That is quite odd, your command line is correct. If either the ISO or the mountpoint were missing, you'd definitely get a different error. I think such error should only be displayed if you typed `sudo mount /media/fakecd`. Could you show us your /etc/fstab?

Comment: This error mostly got if "loop" word is ommited, so the `/path/to/your.iso` is understood as option, not device. To exclude such situation command could look like `sudo mount /path/to/your.iso /media/fakecd -o loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you how to do this via terminal, but I used to mount an ISO with `nautilus`, by right-clicking the file and selecting something like <kbd>open with...</kbd> > <kbd>archive mounter</kbd> (I don't know the exact words as I use the German translation). Then it should appear in the left half of the `nautilus` explorer, near the network places. I hope you can do something with this advice. Greetings!

Comment: Or, even better, > "Disk Image Mounter"

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether the partition(/path/to/your.iso)  you are trying to mount has entries in the /etc/fstab file.

If the entries in not present in the fstab files,only root user is set tomount the partition.To do automate mount please try to add them in the fstab file.

Comment: How can I add entries in fstab?

Comment: To add the entries in the ftstab,Please follow the below steps               open the file /etc/fstab and then copy the command                  /path/to/your.iso  /media/fakecd  xfs defaults,auto 1 1                              xfs - external device file type.